# Запрос JSON-RPC на Java

Tags: java, json, rpc

Граждане, всем привет!)

Может кто объяснить мне требования для передачи JSON-RPC запроса?
То есть есть сервер на какой-то машине, и нужно передать запрос json-rpc 2.0. 
Но я не понимаю, что я должен учитывать при передаче. Длину запроса, кол-ство байт, не знаю даже?

Есть код на C# который работает корректно, а вот написать его же на java не хватает понимания как работает запрос.

Answer (score 3):

[Спецификация](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) JSON-RPC довольно проста, в ней вы можете найти примеры запросов. Если JSON-RPC сервер работает поверх HTTP (спецификацией не оговаривается вид транспорта, может использоваться и просто TCP), то обычно нужно отправить POST-запрос с телом, содержащим JSON вида:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "имя_вызываемого_метода",
    "params": параметры_передаваемые_в_метод,
    "id": идентификатор_запроса
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Даже на wiki можно найти [примеры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC).
Если их недостаточно, то можно посмотреть [спецификацию](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification), как советовал товарищ [@kmv](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178379/kmv), либо заглянуть на [хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150803/).

Если по простому, то традиционно (хотя и не обязательно) JSON-RPC используется для предоставления веб-сервисов, то есть через HTTP.
Обращение к веб-сервису осуществляется запросом [HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) методом [POST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)), есть некоторые [ограничения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request), определяемые в основном средой реализации (т.е. серверной частью).
То есть на точку доступа (как правило она одна) направляется JSON (строка) согласно [спецификации](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification), и ожидается ответ от сервера.

```
>>  { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "web_function", "params": { "var1": 4, "var2": 42 } }  
<<  { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": 46, "id": null }


>> { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "web_function", "params": [ 'a', 'b' ], "id": 1 }
<< { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": 'ba', "id": 1 }


>> { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "web_function_2", "params": [ 'c', 1 ], "id": 2 }
<< { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "error": { "code": -32601, "message": "Method not found." }, "id": "2" }
```

Тем не менее ни кто не запрещает использовать в качестве транспорта [WS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) в своих веб-приложениях.
Для остальных приложений выбор транспорта ещё больше, и ограничения накладываются только сервером и конкретной реализацией.